# Phone memory shows as nearly full in PC, but is not

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage

ATT version of Galaxy S3
running cm-10.1.2-d2att.zip

http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=d2att

I seem to be having a storage issue. I'm guessing it was while I was changing to a new a ROM. I wiped the device and did a fresh install, but used titanium to restore settings.

the 12 gig internal reports having less than 1 gig free, but I can only find ~3 gig of information. (see pic)[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what CM10.1.2 points to: Could it be you switched from Android 4.1 to Android 4.2 with the latest update? If so, it might be the storage location has changed, IMHO from `/sdcard` to `/storage/sdcard0` (I have no reference here, so I cannot check the exact locations). So on the Windows machine, it only shows `/storage/sdcard0` now (as a Fuse "drive"), and you don't see the entire storage. Please check directly on the device.

Comment: @Izzy IIRC Google changed the layout of system under 4.2, `/storage/sdcard0` to `/storage/primary/legacy/` - possible driver update/refresh?

Comment: @t0mm13b That's what I was referring to. I saw the very same issue reported elsewhere (cannot remember the link), being caused by an update from one JB version to the next. During that process, data was *duplicated* from its original place to the new path (i.e. copied to the new and still left in the old place), which caused free storage to "drop", logically.

Answer (score 0):

Try reflashing the Rom with full wipe again but don't restore anything with Titanium Backup.

similar problems usually happen when I used to restore *data* with **Titanium Backup** especially if the android upgrade from Rom to another is significant (e.g 4.1 to 4.2).

please try this and tell what happens :)

Edit: added my comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Makes sense now to me: Could be connected to the "storage issue" mentioned in the comments on the question itself.

Comment: I actually wish he know the solution to this problem, because I'm going to flash 4.3 GE Rom on my HTC One and I don't know if I can restore some of the app data (like games)...

Comment: Maybe you contact Joël (the dev of Titanium) and ask for advice? He's usually quite responsive. If you get an answer that sheds more light, please don't forget to let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

How about your internal SD and emulated SD card free space? Sometime your phone has duplicate files on emulated SD and internal SD. Sometime it may be an issue with the setting restore. When you're switching ROM (different android version), it's not recommended restore data using old ROM backup.

Comment: I'll try this out. Are you saying that when you do a fresh rom install you (re)configure all your apps?

Comment: Yes definitely, most of the ROM developer mention don't restore data using TB or any other backup apps.